# VBA to get Computers VPN State

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, vpn

I'm trying to build into my code a way of seeing if the computer can reach the SQL Server that it accesses.

The issue is that I can't just get the network state as to reach the SQL Server the computer needs to be on the VPN (through Cisco)

I've seen the Cisco API reference in VBA but have no idea how to use this, and also not 100% sure this would be a fail safe method of testing

I've had two ideas of doing this:

1. Ping the SQL Server (my preferred) - I've tried using this code but it just comes back with "passed" whether the server is connected or not

My function:

```
Sub test()
' SQL Server address instead of xxxxxxx
If Ping("xxxxxxx") Then
    MsgBox "Passed", vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "Failed", vbOKOnly
End If
End Sub
Public Function Ping(ByVal ComputerIP As String) As Boolean
    'You can use also name of computer
    ' Return TRUE, if pin was successful
   Dim oPingResult As Variant
    For Each oPingResult In GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2").ExecQuery _
        ("SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '" & ComputerName & "'")
        If IsObject(oPingResult) Then
            If oPingResult.StatusCode = 0 Then
                Ping = True
                'Debug.Print "ResponseTime", oPingResult.ResponseTime 'You can also return ping time
               Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

2. My other idea was if the computer is connected to the VPN the Ethernet LAN adapter changes to have a connection-specific DNS suffix (however this I think is a virtual adapter so I can't just test the name as it might not be on the same adapter in repeated tests)

Therefore my second idea was to scan through all of the connections retrieving their Connection-specific dns suffix and test for the correct name however I'm not sure how to extract this information.

Comment: Your question title seems a little different from what you are actually asking. Are you asking if you can test the SQL Server connection, or how to determine if a particular network adapter is connected. (For the first case just try to connect to the server and if you can, you can and if you can't, you can't).

Comment: Where I work we use a secured network connection (whether this be on VPN or LAN) I need the workbook to get this information to see whether it can connect to the SQL server. If so the code will continue. If not it will run something else so that the workbook is used differently. I need to test for this and I don't want the code to just wait until it timesout.

Comment: OK, so your question has nothing to do with SQL Server. FYI the correct thing to do in your situation is to attempt the connection at the point of use and then deal with failure. When you delete a file you don't consider every possible way deletion can go wrong and test them all before performing the delete; you just delete the file and handle the exception if it fails. The first approach leads to race conditions and does not guarantee success. The second guarantees success if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have fixed the code above - Just realised I was calling the wrong variable to ping.

Should be:

`Sub test()
' SQL Server address instead of xxxxxxx
If Ping("xxxxxxx") Then
    MsgBox "Passed", vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "Failed", vbOKOnly
End If
End Sub
Public Function Ping(ByVal ComputerIP As String) As Boolean
    'You can use also name of computer
    ' Return TRUE, if pin was successful
   Dim oPingResult As Variant
    For Each oPingResult In GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2").ExecQuery _
        ("SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '" & ComputerIP & "'")
        If IsObject(oPingResult) Then
            If oPingResult.StatusCode = 0 Then
                Ping = True
                'Debug.Print "ResponseTime", oPingResult.ResponseTime 'You can also return ping time
               Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function`

Works now